# Dual monitor not working after regular update on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, freeze, multiple-monitors

I ran the software updater on my laptop yesterday. Today when I plugged in my second screen through the HDMI port, the screen on my laptop screen froze and I had to hard reboot it and remove the screen to get it working normally.

If I boot into Ubuntu with the HDMI cable plugged in then it works fine until I log in (but nothing is visible on my second screen). After logging in, everything freezes.

When it freezes, the Unity title bar ends up in the middle of my laptop screen and my mouse cursor is not moving.

I tried reinstalling xserver-xorg, but it was of no use.

How should I proceed?

Comment: I have the same problem, but with HDMI disconnected in single monitor mode, the mouse freezes periodically. Switching to a text terminal and back makes the mouse pointer able to move again for a little while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this may be related to a Nvidia driver update rolled out some time around December 11th 2014 (that's the date `/var/log/apt/history.log` shows on my laptop).

My laptop has an Ivy Bridge CPU with a GTX-680M Nvidia card. By going to “NVIDIA X Server Settings”, choosing “PRIME Profiles” and “Intel (Power Saving Mode)”, I can turn off the Nvidia card and switch to just using the onboard Intel graphics, which, although not ideal, at least renders my machine usable again in dual-monitor mode.

Rolling back the Nvidia drivers to the previous version may also work, but I haven't tried that.